# Objects stored in list have the same ID or point to the same object

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make a simple CRUD of manager clients (in C, a language I'm not very familiar with but I have no choice) on a server which can connect with sockets. The server will hold 10 simultaneous connections at the same time by working with a session ID. The problem is that when I print the list after adding 10 clients, it shows a list with 10 times the same object (or 10 objects with the same ID, this is where I'm a bit confused).

This is how I declared the struct of the manager client and declared the list (that can hold 10 of them) :

```
typedef struct Mana_client {
    int client_id;
    int timestamp_connection;
    char privilege_level;
}Mana_client;

Mana_client *mana_client_list[10];
srand(time(NULL)); // is called once when initializing the thread.
```

This is how I wrote 'adding a client to the list' :

```
int add_mana_client()
{
    int i=0;
    int client_id = 0;
    int timestamp = 0;
    Mana_client client = { client_id, timestamp, 1};
    client_id = rand()%100000;
    timestamp = time(NULL);
    client.client_id =  &client_id;
    client.timestamp_connection = &timestamp;
    for(i=0; i <10; i++)
    {
        if(mana_client_list[i] == NULL){
            printf("%u. Empty spot in list\n", i);
            if(!contains_mana_client_id(client_id)){
                printf("%u. Adding client... (with ID%u)\n", i, client.client_id);
                mana_client_list[i] = &client;
                return client_id;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is how I check if a client with the same ID is already in the list :

```
int contains_mana_client_id(int id)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i <10; i++)
    {
        if(mana_client_list[i] != NULL){
            if(id == mana_client_list[i]->client_id){
                printf("%u. Client with ID=%u found.\n", i, id);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, to check the list and its clients :

```
void print_mana_client_list()
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Printing list of mana clients...\n\n");
    for(i=0; i <10; i++)
    {
        if(mana_client_list[i] != NULL){
            printf("%u. Client with ID=%u.\n", i, mana_client_list[i]->client_id);
        }else{
            printf("%u. Empty.\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

After running the method to add a client 12 times in a row and printing the list, I get this output :

1. Empty spot in list
2. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
   Management client added (with ID=41).
3. Empty spot in list
4. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
   Management client added (with ID=18467).
5. Empty spot in list
6. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
   Management client added (with ID=6334).
7. Empty spot in list
8. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
   Management client added (with ID=26500).
9. Empty spot in list
10. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=19169).
11. Empty spot in list
12. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=15724).
13. Empty spot in list
14. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=11478).
15. Empty spot in list
16. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=29358).
17. Empty spot in list
18. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=26962).
19. Empty spot in list
20. Adding client... (with ID94630956)
    Management client added (with ID=24464).

Management client added (with ID=0).

Management client added (with ID=0).

Printing list of mana clients...

1. Client with ID=3435973836.
2. Client with ID=3435973836.
3. Client with ID=3435973836.
4. Client with ID=3435973836.
5. Client with ID=3435973836.
6. Client with ID=3435973836.
7. Client with ID=3435973836.
8. Client with ID=3435973836.
9. Client with ID=3435973836.
10. Client with ID=3435973836.

Personally I think the problem is related to the way I store or pass the objects/values but I'm not entirely sure. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Replaced the code by mana_client_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(Mana_client));
*mana_client_list[i] = client; which still fills the list with copies of the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because they *are* the same. When you do

```
mana_client_list[i] = &client;
```

you use a pointer to the local variable, all the time. Instead you should create a new instance of the structure for each iteration in the loop. For that you need to use `malloc` to allocate memory for the structure. Don't forget to `free` that memory when you're done with it.

This will also solve another problem you have, and that is that you save pointers to a local variable, which will go out of scope once the function `add_mana_client` returns. Using that pointer after the function returns is a case of *undefined behavior*, and you're just lucky it works.

---

A simple way, without making to many modifications to your current code, might be something like the following code to replace the current `mana_client_list[i] = &client;` line:

```
mana_client_list[i] = malloc(sizeof(Mana_client));
*mana_client_list[i] = client;
```

This allocates a new structure, and copies the already initialized structure to that new structure.

Comment: So when I write Mana_client client = { client_id, timestamp, 1}; it doesn't create a new instance of the struct each time the method is called? In Java I would write it like Mana_client client = new Mana_client( client_id, timestamp, 1); Is there an equivalent in C to do the same thing?

Comment: @ChukUltima Yes a new instance is created every time the function is called. But then there's the question of *undefined behavior*. You simply can not store a pointer to a local variable, and expect access to it to work from outside the function.